# can not open folder structure at sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

[folder can't open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3XfJ.png)

I can not open the public folder, but when I refresh Folders and it's works. How can I fix this? I don't wanna click refresh Folders every single time if I want to open this folder. Please, help me.

Comment: looks like this is a known bug: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/151

Comment: I try to add follow_symlinks: true but it's still not work. Could you help me?